# Proper Bash reference manual

Tags: bash, shell

After searching the web for some time, I can't seem to find a documentation of the following Bash option.

```
-n, in the context of if [ -n $variable ]
```

To my knowledge, this option test if a certain variable is set, but I want to read it in a reference manual.

I've come across the following option on the man pages of Bash

```
--norc
```

but, I'm pretty sure -n is not the abbrevation for --norc.

Can someone pinpoint a documentation reference manual of Bash that explains the function of -n.

Comment: `man [` or `man test` (`[` is an other name for `test`). Or use Bash's `[[` and read *SHELL GRAMMAR*, *Compound Commands* in Bash's man page.

Comment: @Biffen It should be `help [` or  `help test` since nowadays `test` is likely a builtin.

Comment: @hek2mgl True. But the contents should be similar, especially regarding `-n`.

Comment: (@MusséRedi Did you know you can search in man pages? Try `/`. (It depends on the pager.))

Comment: I did, but I searched for -n as opposed to -n string. I stopped searching after a few matches of -n.

Comment: @MusséRedi Try refining the search. `^\s*-n\b` found it as the second occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man bash` Everything you ever needed to know about bash is in the man page.

```
   -n string
          True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

To search man pages when you open them use `/`. I did this `/-n` . Note the space is important or you find the `-norc` items etc.

Comment: better to add that you can search in `man` by entering `/` and search string, and then by clicking `n` you can go to the next instance.

Comment: I'll update the answer.

Comment: The canonical documentation for bash is in "info" format. `info bash` should show it to you (if the documentation is installed on your system). I believe the man page contains all the information in the "info" manual, but "info" manuals can be easier to navigage. The manual is also available [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).